# How to remove white space form right side in wordrpess in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How fast to determine which element shifted out border, Seems there some margin more than needed. How I can determine it?
This is link on page that is broken in mobile http://test2.kselax.ru/2013/01/11/markup-html-tags-and-formatting/

[image]

I did this style * {border: 2px solid red;} and no one element shifted under html block. When I do *{ margin: 0 !important; } This is help to correct. Seems there javascript probably add that shift, or I don't know who.

I need some methods for fast determining element with big margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `overflow:hidden` to `.container-fluid` seems to fix the problem

```
.container-fluid, .container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works. Before I used body, html{overflow: hidden;}, and this didn't help and now even that work.
Common rule at first do for each element border using *{border: 02.px solid red;} and then if not see shifted border, apply for body or other element overflow. If we don't see shifted border, it means shifted margin that we can't see visually probably....